# Under the hood of new

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator

I was discussing doron's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559938/memory-leak-unit-test-c/3560818?noredirect=1#comment21708367_3560818) question, and it was said that

> [one] will probably find that the C++ standard library defines new to
>   use malloc under the hood.

I'm wondering if this is true. Does the C++ Standard define `new` to use `malloc`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does the C++ standard define new to use malloc?

The *C++ Standard* (meaning the Standard document that defines the C++ Language) doesn't define `operator new` in terms of `malloc()`. However, it is plausible that most *implementations* of the C++ Standard Library use `malloc()` to allocate memory.

Per Paragraph 18.6.1.1/4 of the C++11 Standard (about `operator new`):

> *Default behavior*
>
> - Executes a loop: Within the loop, the function first attempts to
>     allocate the requested storage. **Whether the attempt involves a call to the Standard C library function `malloc` is unspecified**.

Comment: Relevant http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_opnt.cc?view=markup

Answer (score 3):

> Does the C++ standard define new to use malloc?

No, although many implementations do that for the default `new` implementation (it doesn't make much sense to provide separated heaps for `malloc` and `new`).

Also, the allocator function used by `new` is customizable (see §3.7.4.1), so it's particularly wrong to assume that `new' will always call`malloc`, even on a given implementation.

Comment: Props for explicitly calling out custom `new`

Answer (score 0):

No, `malloc` just allocates memory. But `new` allocates memory and call constructors (if needs).

MAYBE in some part of implementation of `new` you find `malloc`-like mechanism as memory allocator.

Comment: He asked if new uses malloc, not if they are the same thing. And obviously aren't since one is a function and one is a statement.

Comment: @LtWorf: that isn't strictly true. `new` is an operator, and `::operator new()` is just a function.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so since `malloc` is not aware of constructors and you need a little extra than declaring a chunk of memory